# Difference between old and new LG UltraFine 5K(4K) Displays

Tags: thunderbolt-display

The Apple Store shows the LG UltraFine 5K Display and LG UltraFine 4K display marked as "new".

I have found reviews on YouTube of the same two displays dated 2 years ago.

Does this mean that there are both an old and new version of the displays with the same names?

If so, what is the difference between the old and the new versions?

Comment: The question might also be off-topic because it‘s not about an Apple product or its use. But depending on your research the difference (or rather the impact it may have) may be on-topic so let‘s see how this turns out.

Comment: Still, this is the product developed by LG and Apple togather, available on Apple store only and dedicated exclusively for MAC users.

Comment: Agreed, that‘s why the impact of any difference found may very well validate a question. But comparing two products based on their available specification is something I consider to be basic research.

Comment: @ФилиппЦветков We use these with PC and Mac at work, but the point of showing some research is what will make it on topic / clear for our high reputation users to review the temporary hold. Shopping questions are off topic, but questions about how to determine compatibility can be on topic if they aren't too broad or wikipedia

Comment: @bmike If you can lift the hold, I can answer the question. The reason behind the "new" sign is that LG/Apple has made an updated version of those displays for sale in July. The updated version works with the iPad Pro (USB-C), and there's a few other differences as well I can detail.

Comment: @jksoegaard  Can you edit the question to make clear what version is in question? 4 displays seems pretty broad since each is different and each was new at one point.

Comment: @bmike I don't think it gets much more clearer than this, but I have tried editing it. Essentially there's two displays - the 4K and the 5K from LG. They have both been updated in July, so that there is a new version with the same name as the old version.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, LG and Apple have made new versions available of the LG UltraFine Displays - under the same name. The model numbers are different though.

The old 5K version had model number 27MD5KA, whereas the new version has model number 27MD5KL.

The new 5K version adds support for USB-C - the old version supported only Thunderbolt 3. This is probably not a big deal for Mac users, but if you have an iPad Pro it means that you can connect the iPad Pro directly to the display over USB-C.

In addition the new 5K version ups power delivery over Thunderbolt 3 to 94 watt from 85 watts. It's probably not important for most, as 85 watts is enough to charge a MacBook Pro.

All in all relatively minor changes, but only for the better.

The 4K version is a different deal though. The new revision is basically a completely different display. The size has increased from 21.5" to 23.7" while the resolution was lowered from 4096x2304 to 3840x2160. In addition, the 4 USB-C ports on the old display has been changed to 3 USB-C ports and 2 Thunderbolt 3 ports with the latter supporting 85W of power delivery in total.

The old 4K version had model number 22MD4KA-B, whereas the new version has model number 24MD4KL.

Comment: I recently bought what I thought was a 27MD5KL-B display via Amazon Renew https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/B07XVLVD22/ref=ppx_od_dt_b_asin_title_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1

and when I got it (very strange) it came in an MD5KA box, but the model # on the display itself says 27MD5KB

should I ask for a return?

Comment: If you've got the right product and only the box is wrong - then it pretty much depends on whether you think the box is important to you?

Comment: All I know about Apple is that it's a fruit company that Ray Babbitt has so successfully invested into. I joined this SE solely to upvote your answer and say thanks to you! I'm a PC user, unable to find a 24-27" 220+ DPI monitor outside of the Apple world, as they apparently only grow on apple trees; none in 3(!!!) yrs since your answer! Yours is the only out there that lists all the recent and current LG hi-DPI models made for Apple. Thank you soo much! I have a TB 4 card with DP 1.4 input supposed to be connected to a video output; never tried, but crossing my fingers never failed me... :)

Answer (score 15):

### 27" Models

27MD5KL

- current (as of 2020) revision updated in 2019
- added: usb-c compatibility
- changed: contrast - 1100:1
- changed: charging - 94w
- changed: thunderbolt controller: Titan Ridge (EDID id: 5b74)

27MD5KB

- previous
- contrast - 1200:1
- charging - 85w
- thunderbolt controller: Alpine Ridge (EDID id: 5b11)

27MD5KA

- original version
- WARNING: this model caused interference issues
- sold for a short time only at Apple stores before being removed from shelves

Comment: There is a free repair program for any of these when interference was suspected. Great information on the models. Also USB-C is very noisy so even the improved ones can impact 2.4 GHz with all Mac and third party cables and devices perfect / correct / fixed.

Comment: Updated with changed TB controller info. USB-C is also 4k only for all devices, not just iPad. Noticed in a different thread someone claimed 4k was an iPad specific limitation.

Comment: Both [27MD5KB-B](https://www.amazon.com/LG-27MD5KB-B-UltraFine-Brightness-Thunderbolt/dp/B0778Z8G5K) and [27MD5KL-B](https://www.amazon.com/LG-27MD5KL-B-Ultrafine-Compatibility-Thunderbolt/dp/B07XV9NQSJ) on Amazon say they support USB-C. Why did you say 27MD5KL added USB-C compatibility?

Comment: Thunderbolt 3 terminates with a USB-c connector, which is what the Amazon listing is referring to with Thunderbolt 3 (USB-c).

[L-model specs on LG](https://www.lg.com/us/monitors/lg-27md5kl-b-5k-uhd-led-monitor)
- Thunderbolt 3 and USB-c listed as inputs. 
- comes with separate Thunderbolt 3 and USB-c cables
- [Verge Review confirming](https://www.theverge.com/circuitbreaker/2019/7/30/20748047/lg-ultrafine-5k-display-apple-new-model)
- [9to5Mac Review confirming](https://9to5mac.com/2019/07/30/new-lg-ultrafine-5k-display/)

Comment: ...(continued) [K-model specs on LG](https://www.lg.com/us/business/desktop-monitors/lg-27MD5KB-B)
-Thunderbolt 3 listed as only input
-comes with Thunderbolt 3 cable only

Thunderbolt 3 and USB-c compatibility are often incorrectly used interchangeably, but it is controller and cable dependent. LG changed both for the L-model update.